# Create a loop that asks values, store the values and later print the average?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create an algorithm that take values (wages) from the user and later do the average wage (Just like a input loop, storing all the input values until you type the command to stop). Then I have to print the percentage of people with wages above £100.

I'm new to Python.

I successfully created the input loop, but have no idea on how to store these values calculate the average later.

```py
    print("Type the wages, when finished type -1")    
    wages = int(input("Type the wage"))    
    count = 1    
    exit = -1    
    while exit != wages:    
       wages = int(input("Type the wage: "))     
       count += 1    
    def average():    
        wages / count    

    if wages == exit:    
        print(average)
```

Comment: Okay, so here's my question before I can help you.  We need a bit more information to be able to explain what's needed.  Do you want it to only accept a certain amount of wages?  Like, only 5 inputs for example?  Or do you want it to continue until the user enters a keyword?

Comment: No, the amount that the user wants to input and then do the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print("Type the wages, when finished type -1")
wages = int(input("Type the wage: "))
wages_list = []
while wages !=-1:
    wages = int(input("Type the wage: "))
    if wages!=-1:
        wages_list.append(wages)
if wages_list:
    print("Average is :",sum(wages_list)/len(wages_list))
```

Try this

Comment: Glad to help you with your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Before your `while` loop, you can create an empty list for storing the wages:

```
wageList = []
```

*Within* the loop, you can add each wage to the list (*before* the next `input`):

```
wageList.append(wages)
```

Then at the end, you can get the average:

```
if len(wageList) == 0:
    print("No wages given")
else:
    print("Average was {}".format(sum(wageList) / len(wageList)))
```

By using the length of the list, you don't need to store the count.

---

In addition, some of your code is wrong and/or superfluous:

```
def average():    
    wages / count    // You probably wanted to return this :-)

if wages == exit:    
    print(average)   // average is a function, you would want to use average()
```

My advice would be to ditch that since the code is simple enough that it can be done in a single snippet of code (without functions).

---

The number of people with wages over £100 can be obtained with:

```
num = len([item for item in wagesList if item > 100])
```

though, if you wanted to stay at the "simpler" end of Python (less Pythonic but probably more in line with the level of this classwork), you could just use a loop:

```
num = 0
for item in wagesList:
    if item > 100:
        num += 1
```

The percentage is then (assuming non-zero size, so check that the same as I have above):

```
num * 100 / len(wagesList)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
total = 0
count = 0
while True:
    inval = int(input("Type the Wage: "))
    if inval == -1:
        break
    total = total + inval
    count = count + 1
print("average is " + str(total / count))
```

Comment: Just a small snippet of advice, you may want to check for `count == 0` before calculating the average.

Comment: @paxdiablo This was a quick and dirty solution so I didn't add case checking etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
persons = []
wages_persons = []
print("Enter person name, when finished type exit")
person = input("Enter person name: ")
while person != 'exit':
    persons.append(person)
    print("Type the wages, when finished type -1")
    wages = int(input("Type the wage: "))
    wages_list = []
    while wages !=-1:
        wages = int(input("Type the wage: "))
        if wages!=-1:
            wages_list.append(wages)
    if wages_list:
        avg = sum(wages_list)/len(wages_list)
        print("Average of {} is {}".format(person,avg))
        wages_persons.append(avg)
    person = input("Enter person name: ")

wages_over_100 = [x for x in wages_persons if x>100]
print("Total {}% persons have wages avarage above 100$".format((len(wages_over_100)/len(wages_persons))*100))
```

This would work according to your expectations.